# Hydrogen peroxide: catalyst changes colour during peroxide decomposition

Tags: reaction-mechanism, catalysis

When adding iron(III) chloride to hydrogen peroxide, the hydrogen peroxide decomposes.

Iron(III) chloride is a **catalyst**.

But when it is first added, it changes its colour to dark brown, then near the end it turns to orange.

> Why does the colour change?

I heard that it has to do something with reaction intermediate. Correct?

It is seen on: [iron(III) chloride](https://youtu.be/qT3mJrmhJHU?t=2m54s)

Also, the colour changes when different catalyst is used like iron(III) nitrate and potassium iodide [potassium iodide](https://youtu.be/mNRUlQ1TfV4?t=3m16s), [iron(III) nitrate](https://youtu.be/lWkfJsugkwE)

Answer (score 4):

[Recently, I answered your question and relevant information can be found from that answer.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/66949/demonstrating-decomposition-of-hydrogen-peroxide-using-ironiii-nitrate-catalys/67059#67059)

At first, I thought that the brown colour is due to ferrous chloride that formed during the course of reaction but since the reaction is occuring in a aqueous solution, it should be green in colour. Ferrous chloride is brown in anhydrous form. So I thought to be either due to formation of a complex, [iron(II, III) oxide($\ce{Fe2O3}$),](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(III)_oxide) or [iron(III) oxide-hydroxide($\ce{FeOOH.nH2O}$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(III)_oxide-hydroxide) or a mixed salt of oxide-chloride i.e. [iron oxychloride($\ce{FeOCl}$).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_oxychloride)

The following information is from the paper 2 of that answer:

> According to the mechanism proposed by KREMER and STEIN, **an
>   intermediate oxygen complex of iron with oxidation number +V is
>   primarily formed by the reaction of $\ce{Fe^3+}$ with $\ce{H2O2}$.
>   This complex reacts with another $\ce{H2O2}$ molecule to water and
>   oxygen thereby reforming $\ce{Fe^3+}$.**
>
> $$\ce{Fe^3+ + H2O2 <=> [Fe^{III}OOH]^2+ + 2H+ <=> [Fe^{V}O]^3+ + H2O ->[H2O2] Fe^3+ + 2H2O + O2}$$
>
> According to the mechanism proposed by HABER and WEISS the $\ce{Fe^3+}$ ions
>   initiate a radical reaction, after which the chain reaction consumes
>   the hydrogen peroxide. This mechanism can explain the high reaction
>   rate very well.
>
> Chain initiation:  $\ce{Fe^3+ + H2O2 <=> [Fe^{III}OOH]^2+ + 2H+ <=> Fe^2+ + HOO. + H+}$
>
> Chain propagation: $\ce{Fe^2+ + H2O2 -> Fe^3+ + 2OH.}$ 
>   $\ce{Fe^3+ + H2O2 + OH. -> Fe^3+ + HOO. + H2O -> Fe^2+ + H+ + O2 + H2O }$

That intermediate oxygen complex of iron with oxidation number +V maybe responsible for the brown colour of solution.

---

As for the potassium iodide, the color you are seeing is basically food coloring. Various food coloring  is used to make the foam produced colorful. If food-color is not used, still color is seen. That color is basically color of pure soap foam. [This elephant toothpaste experiment not uses food-color but still it has color that is color of soap-foam.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTfMrx7275w)

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this reaction before, but if I recall correctly, chloride ions ($\ce{Cl-}$) are known to give a solution an orange appearance.

I am assuming that the $\ce{H2O2}$ oxidizes the iron, leaving free chloride ions in solution.

Comment: Does NaCl dissolved in water appear orange?

Comment: No, I do not believe it does. It's possible I was thinking of chlorine  - in which case chloride ions would be reacting with each-other near the end of the reaction.

Comment: Why would hydrogen peroxude oxidize the iron? The catalyst is not being used up

Comment: That is indeed the definition of a catalyst.

But, I think the oxidation would actually be from O2.      

 H2O2 ->  H2O + O2      
O2 + Fe(III) -> Fe2O3       

I'm mostly just speculating... Sorry

Comment: If the solution only contains water, hydrogen peroxide, and iron chloride.. And the solution is a different color at the end of the reaction. There is no possible way that there are not any new-formed compounds.

As water and H2O2 are both clear, and O2 would either evaporate, or remain dissolved.

And dissolved O2 would still be clear.

Answer (score -1):

The orange-yellow colour is caused by the chloride ions taking the place of water in the coordination complex, anhydrous iron (III) chloride is a dark black or purple crystal, it's easier to see with a bigger anion that won't interfere with the hexaaquairon (III) complex. The red iron (IV) solution is formed on addition of hydrogen peroxide to the orange solution of [pentaaquachloridoiron (III)]2+ chloride solution turning some of those metal ion complexes to [tetraaquaoxoiron(IV)]+ chloride ions.