# What are the most potent hydrogen peroxide decomposition catalysts available to an amateur?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, home-experiment, catalysis, decomposition

Some months ago I was playing with $60\,\%$ $\ce{H2O2}$ and unknowingly I used a silver spoon to transfer the liquid from a container, and the peroxide immediately started bubbling (it did look and sound like violent boiling) around the spoon.

Are there solids or thick liquids available to an amateur that are even more potent in catalysing the decomposition of $\ce{H2O2}?$

Comment: I did not downvote, but I am a bit concerned about the “playing with” 60% hydrogen peroxide. It is dangerous, causes nasty painful burns (worse than the 30% grade) and practically everything catalyzes its highly exothermic decomposition. Silver, including sterling silver teaspoons, is one of the many substances that act as efficient catalysts. You may well be lucky nothing really bad happened. Please read up on hydrogen peroxide and be safe: use the appropriate PPE!

Comment: “And it is a nerve-wracking experience to put your ear against a propellant tank and hear it go "glub" -long pause- "glub" and so on. After such an experience many people, myself (particularly) included, tended to look dubiously at peroxide and to pass it by on the other side.”
― John D. Clark, Ignition!: An informal history of liquid rocket propellants

Comment: What "potency" do you mean? While probably nothing compares with catalase present in a humble potato, it's concentration in tissues is low. BTW if you somehow have access to 60 % H2O2, you should already know such things.

Comment: Well there is [manganese dioxide](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7759/reaction-intermediates-of-mno2-catalyzed-h2o2-decomposition-reaction), there is [iron(III) nitrate](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/66949/demonstrating-decomposition-of-hydrogen-peroxide-using-ironiii-nitrate-catalys), there is  [iron(III)chloride](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67278/hydrogen-peroxide-catalyst-changes-colour-during-peroxide-decomposition).

Comment: Another thing is what's "liquids available to an amateur" supposed to be mean, when hardly any "amateur" has access to 60 % H2O2!